# Web help to Sharepoint site

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've some basic project documentation (help). 
It is a index page with frames and a lot of html files with images.
To make a better use i want to deploy it on Sharepoint site (with configured search).

Easiest way to do this its a iframe webpart, but it's not a good decision.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the help files under _layouts directory.
2. Use the Page Viewer WebPart to place each of this page in its individual SharePoint pages.
3. Crawl the SharePoint pages only.